# Redirect to existing view when getting error (404, 500, etc) django

Tags: python, django, redirect, error-handling

When my cookie session expires it gives 500 error and I would like to redirect it to the login.

I've added the url to override 500 handler.

**myapp/urls.py**

```
handler500 = 'myapp.login.views.signin'
```

But this alone doesn't work.

So I tried adding the function server_error:

**myapp/urls.py**

```
handler500 = 'myapp.login.views.server_error'
```

**myapp/login/views.py**

```
def server_error(request, template_name='templatename.html'):

    try:
        template = loader.get_template(template_name)
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return http.HttpResponseServerError('<h1>Server Error (500)</h1>')
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render(Context({})))
```

**myapp/login/templates**

```
templatename.html
```

The **error** is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/user/ENV/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 64, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/ENV/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/ENV/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/user/ENV/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 242, in handle_uncaught_exception
    callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve500()
  File "/home/user/ENV/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 403, in resolve500
    return self._resolve_special('500')
  File "/home/user/ENV/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 391, in _resolve_special
    return get_callable(callback), {}
  File "/home/user/ENV/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user/ENV/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 101, in get_callable
    not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)


ImportError: No module named login
```

Comment: An expired cookie shouldn't cause a server error. It would be better to try to fix that rather than hijacking the `handler500` to redirect to the login page.

Comment: What should be the response then?

Comment: I don't think you should write a `server_error` view at all. Fix the view that gives the error instead. You haven't shown the traceback for the error or the view, so I can't help with that.

Comment: Do I need to copy the whole traceback?

Comment: Yes, please include the whole traceback.

Comment: It looks like `myapp/login` might be missing the `__init__.py` file. I think that error is from the `handler500`, not the original view. Remove `handler500 = 'myapp.login.views.server_error'` from your urls and post the original error message.

Comment: Doesn't give an error if I remove the handler but how can I override the 500 error then?

Comment: We're going round in circles here ... I don't think you shouldn't override the 500 error handler at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124560/discussion-between-didina-deen-and-alasdair).